# The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, openstack

i am trying to upload file to cloud through openstack api. and got sucess but when uploading large file (> 1 GB) uploading stops with error

The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)

```
NSInputStream *iStream = [[NSInputStream alloc]initWithFileAtPath:filePath];
self.request.HTTPBodyStream = iStream;
```

i am not able to debug this issue. so anyone please tell me how can i identify this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any logs at the server end?

Comment: no i don't have, but uploading fails after 52% every time.

Comment: You need to check if there is a file size limit on the server. Try with a smaller file, just under and just over the size where the failure is...

Comment: Yes, i checked. is there any limit of NSStream ? because i am initialised NSInputStream from file file path. here is another way to write stream to OutputStream as in case of java. its working fine in android.

Comment: I'm getting this error for my website whose SSL Certificate is not installed properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077284/what-is-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-code-303)